# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './dist/types/single-spa-layout-interface' is not defined by "exports" in

Tags: javascript, typescript, single-spa

Getting following error when run application:

Typescript version - "typescript": "4.7.2"

in package.json

```
"single-spa": "^5.9.3",
"single-spa-layout": "^2.0.1",
"single-spa-web-server-utils": "^2.3.1",
```

node version 16.13.0

```
import {
    constructServerLayout,
    sendLayoutHTTPResponse,
} from "single-spa-layout/dist/types/single-spa-layout-server";
```

```
 Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './dist/types/single-spa-layout-interface' is not defined by "exports" in C:\app1\node_modules\single-spa-la
    yout\package.json
        at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
        at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:440:9)
        at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:692:3)
        at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
        at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (C:\app1\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-suppo
    rt\source-map-support.js:811:30)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {
      code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
```

Answer (score 0):

`single-spa-layout` has not declared that file to be importable.

The [`package.json`](https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-layout/blob/bc3d5e0e9461b4e8142490185e44b56d704072c7/package.json#L8-L21) lists the two possible paths:

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "default": {
        "import": "./dist/esm/single-spa-layout.min.js",
        "require": "./dist/umd/single-spa-layout.min.cjs"
      }
    },
    "./server": {
      "node": {
        "import": "./dist/esm/single-spa-layout-server.min.js",
        "require": "./dist/umd/single-spa-layout-server.min.cjs"
      }
    }
  },
```

Instead of the import statement you are currently using, use:

```js
import {
    constructServerLayout,
    sendLayoutHTTPResponse,
} from "single-spa-layout/server";
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank You But C:\app1\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:843
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index-html.ts:5:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'single-spa-layout/server' or its corresponding type declarations.
5 } from "single-spa-layout/server";

Comment: That's a bug in `single-spa-layout`. I opened a pull request for it: https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-layout/pull/169